# undefined method `each' for "27":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a number of users to be registered in a team , I updated my code so that a team can get registered, however the following error shows up :

```
undefined method `each' for "27":String
NoMethodError in TeamsController#create
```

My code is as follows:

```
class Team<ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :league
belongs_to :seed
has_many :speakers do 
def user(level="1")
    find_by(level: level).user
  end
 end
end
```

my user model looks like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :team

end
```

user model:

```
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :speaking_engagements, class_name: "Speaker"
has_many :teams , through: :speaking_engagements
end
```

speaker model:

```
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Team Controller:

```
class TeamsController<ApplicationController


def new
    @seed=Seed.find_by_id(params[:seed_id])
    @league=current_admin.league
      @team=current_admin.league.teams.build(:seed_id=>@seed,:approved=>false)
    @usernames= @mca.connections.connected.each do |x| x.user end
end

def create
    @league=current_admin.league
    **@team = @league.teams.build(team_params)** #problem appears to be here

  if @team.save
    flash[:notice] = "Team Request Sent!."
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to request team."
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

form looks like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_for @team do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :seed_id, :value => @seed.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :league_id, :value => @league.id %>

            <div class="row">
                <!-- <div class="col-md-8"> -->
                <div class="form-group">

                    <%= f.collection_select :speakers, @usernames,:user_id,:fullname, multiple:true %>
                </div>



                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>


            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Create" , class:"btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Speaker migration:

```
class CreateSpeekers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :speakers do |t|
    t.integer :team_id
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :level

    t.timestamps null: false
   end
 end
end
```

I've been stuck with this error for quite sometime now, I would much appreciate any help!

Full trace:

```
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:355:in `replace'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:47:in `writer'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `speekers='
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
 activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:557:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:280:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `build_association'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:247:in `build_record'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:136:in `build'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:254:in `build'
app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:13:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: can you show the full error?

Comment: and you cannot call `.each` on a string, which is what the error is saying

Comment: yes, I understand we cannot call .each on a string..but the value as we can see in the form , is passed as an integer right? 
I'm not clear about your request about full error, can you please tell me what you would like to further see? Sorry, I'm new to rails so, so many hiccups

Comment: @ShyamPillai Form data is serialized, so the `params` hash will contain string representation of numbers entered in form fields.

Comment: @WizardofOgz, I'm sorry I'm new to rails so I do not know how to convert the datatype(if that's what's to be done) from the form.Can you please help?

Comment: I should have mentioned that ActiveRecord will convert the data types when params are assigned to a model instance.  @ShyamPillai It is not clear where this error is happening or why. It would be helpful if you could provide the error stacktrace showing the file names and lines.

Comment: @WizardofOgz, i have added the full trace.. thats what you requested right?

Comment: the crucial line is the line in your code... ;) please add that as well

Comment: oops..sorry @TheCha͢mp, I've marked it now :)

Comment: Your `team_params` is probably wrong, returning "27" instead of a hash.

Comment: @NilsLandt, do I do something like: 
def team_params
....(:seed_id, :league_id, speakers_attributes:[:team_id,user_id] 
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to my question, thanks to following @WizardOfOgz comment,
so i did the following:

in my teams_controller.rb added the following parameters as permitted :

```
params.require(:team).permit(:user_id, :league_id,:seed_id, :approved, :speakers_attributes=>[:team_id,:user_id])
```

end

then,

in my team.rb added the follwing :

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :speakers
```

further, added nested attributes in the form for team:

```
(in app/views/teams/_form.html.rb )

<h2>Speakers</h2>
    <%= f.fields_for :speakers do |ff| %>
    <div>
    <%= ff.collection_select :user_id, @usernames,:user_id,:fullname%>
     </div>
    <% end %>
```

also since I wanted 3 speakers, I created the following function in helpers/form_helpers:

```
module FormHelper

def setup_team(team)

3.times{
    team.speakers.build
}
    team
  end

end
```

that solved it for me,

thanks to @WizardOfOgz and @RichPeck
also this one really really helped:
http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `"27"` (a user id) is being assigned as the `speakers` association for a team. This is wrong. `speakers` should be assigned instances of `Speaker`.

Unfortunately it gets tough at this point.

What you really need to do is use nested attributes to build the desired speaker records, where each speaker is assign one of the selected user ids. There are many ways to approach this in the UI. There are many great examples of using nested attributes, including this [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: I kinda followed what you said. So i guess I'll have to look for some alternate logic . I'll look up the railscasts episode. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) gives you a lot of interesting methods, including `collection_singular_ids` and `collection_singular_ids=`. The gist of which means you should be able to leverage that getter & setter in your form like this

```
<%= f.collection_select :speaker_ids, @usernames, :user_id, :fullname, multiple: true %>
```

Comment: @BMK5thanks for the answer, I tried your suggestion but it threw up the error "Could not find the speaker with id=26". I followed up on WizardOfOgz suggestion and arrived at the answer. I've posted it here. Thanks :)